# How to create CLCircularRegion using min max geometry bounds

Tags: ios, geolocation, coordinates, radius, geofence

I am working on geofencing where I have to do region monitoring. I am new to geofence topic. I have `bounds`(min-max coordinates) and `geometry` data(all location coordinates). From the below `bounds`, I am creating `CLCircularRegion`.

```
"bounds":{"minlat":50.7238333,"minlon":-1.8716499,"maxlat":50.7248599,"maxlon":-1.8683962}
```

To initialise `CLCircularRegion`, we need `center` and `radius`. I have calculated `centerpoint` using the following formula:

```
center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees((minLat + maxLat) / 2), longitude: CLLocationDegrees((minLng + maxLng) / 2))
```

But I am unable to understand how to calculate radius. 
Any Idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You only have to calculate the distance from center to a point.
Use CLLocation method distance(from:). You can create CLLocation instances with latitude and longitude.

Comment: Do you mean say calculate the distance from center to max lat,long?